# Want A Solution for Automated Job in PHP?

Tags: php, cron

I want to make a script with PHP .
My script has to activate clients accounts.

My first function will grab all login details of clients from the admin panel mostly 100 login or more .

Next I have to go a third party site and login with my client user name and password after they will give a link and I have to grab that link and get the activation code .

After that I have to put the activation code and submit.

All I want to know how can i make this thing automated and queue based. I can make the script but I want a queue system in this script.

After getting no. of job from admin panel it starts doing the job but i have to run 10 or more jobs simultaneously (in parallel) and if any jobs complete it starts another like in IDM (Internet Download Manger). After doing all jobs it will grab a new login from admin and start jobs and so on.

I know about cron but in there I have to command from the cpanel not in php I think something like start cron from php and stop but parallel jobs is also important.

Thanks.
Please help me.

Comment: This may be relevant to your interests. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Comment: Use a database with a table called queue with the data from the admin panel, have one "process" constantly update this table and all of your "child processes" get one item from queue, mark is "processing" and do it. once done, remove it. clean rinse repeat.

Comment: use 1 file that will run by the cronjob every X minutes or have a php with a while true and sleep and that file will consult the database as recommended by Khez and if you have number or requests it will go thru the list and spawn each request into a new php, once that php finish it will at the end update the queue or remove it from the queue allowing u to know it was done to move on for new requests.

Comment: Why is there a question mark in your title? Is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ! i tried it and seems like a table and queue will good option . ia m using mysql_multi to have parallel connection to a page which do the process in that scae i donot need multithreading but doing parallel process !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend Server have a look at zend job queue feature.

It has all the cron possibilities + full logging.